# 3D printer is not printing as well as it used to

Tags: print-quality, bed-leveling

I have recently purchased an Ender 5 Pro and managed to successfully print a large titan model I created with no problem. After this print, I had a bit of a break before getting back to it.

I don't know what has happened but now I just can't get my prints to print properly. I printed a large tower and it left holes in the top surface areas of my prints and my first layers print horribly. I have spent so many hours of every day, leveling the printer time and time again, I cleaned it up, checked for loose screws, etc. Still, to no avail, nothing has fixed the problem and still prints badly.

Maybe my print bed is warped and can't print properly. I am new to this so I don't really know.

I noticed my infill does not print particularly well in my prints and also has holes in the prints, as well as many overhangs, even if they a very small overhangs, become a stringy mess and need a lot of sanding.

[image: Partially printed model with holes in the infill.]

The extruder gears are clean, I took some time to go over the whole printer and clean it up before trying again. I am using the Polyterra filament, it's still the same as when I last printed. My bed temperature is at 55 °C and nozzle is 200 °C, I have tried printing it with the nozzle at 195 °C and up to 210 °C with the same effect still occurring.

Comment: What filament are you using?  Same spool as when you last printed?  What settings (nozzle and bed temperature)?

Comment: You may have under extrusion; there are multiple causes for under extrusion, including crud in your extrusion path.   If you haven't printed for a while, your filament may have absorbed enough humidity to reduce its quality; do you hear snapping and popping while it is printing?

Comment: Um yea I was thinking that, but also noticed when I levelled each corner, it is fine but when I move the nozzle to the centre it's slightly higher, which suggests a warped bed, do you think investing in a glass bed might be a good idea. I changed to a new filament because I had that thought, but still the same problem. I will also maybe change the nozzle to the spare one if that may help. No snapping and popping while printing.

Comment: What is your layer thickness/height? This could be partly caused by layer thicknesses that are too low for your nozzle diameter. Do you still have this issue at 0.2mm layer heights?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like underextrusion.  There are lots of causes, including clogged nozzle and tubes.  Have you checked those?

You should order new nozzles, PTFE tubing and couplers now, even if yours are clean.  You will need them sooner or later, and won't want to wait for delivery.

Many people say Creality couplers don't hold up well, and Capricorn tubes seem to be highly regarded.

Comment: Hey, so I changed the layer height from 0.15 to 0.2mm, already a slight improvement, then decreased the speed by 70%. And noticed a major improvement in the extrusion of the inner layer, hasn't reached the top layer but will find out once print has finished. Turns out it is printing way too fast, also have it set to print in the courner where the bed is more level.

Comment: Excessive extrusion speed could easily cause underextrusion.  Smaller layer height makes this worse as it increases the pressure in the nozzle.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment about creality couplers, In my experience they either lock on permanently or let go with the slightest touch.